# Как вывести данные из изменённой модели

Tags: python, django

помогите пожалуйста решить проблему

я переопределил в модели метод **str**():

```
class Gender(models.Model):     
    gender= models.CharField(
        max_length=40, 
        blank=False,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.status

    @classmethod
    def get_gender_list(self):
        return self.objects.all()
```

views.py:

```
def friends_search(request):    
    t = loader.get_template('friends_search.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {
        'gender_list': Gender.get_gender_list(),
    })  
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

template.html:

```
        {% for key, item in gender_list %}
            -{{ key }}-{{ item }}-
        {% endfor %}
```

fixtures:
    [
        {
            "model": "drummersaransk.Gender",
            "pk": 1,
            "fields": {
                "gender": "Ж"
            }
        },
        {
            "model": "drummersaransk.Gender",
            "pk": 2,
            "fields": {
                "gender": "М"
            }
        } 
    ]

проблема в том, что у меня не получается в шаблоне вывести (id, gender) через цикл. то есть сейчас в вышеприведённом коде выводится пустота

Answer (score 1, accepted):

лень писать много букв:
`self.objects.all()` - выдаст массив объектов!
соответственно или меняй шаблон до вида   `for item in ... item.key item.value` или вьюшку до вида `'gender_list': {item.key: item.value for item in Gender.get_gender_list()},`   или переопределяй метод **iter** в модели до вида yield self.key, self.value

p.s: `for key, value in range(5): pass`